# Can contention for the GPU cause thread blocking? If so, how to fix?

Tags: ios, multithreading, opengl-es, gpu

I have an Objective-C iOS app that is using a third-party C library to render a into an off-screen OpenGL frame buffer.  The rendering happens asynchronously, in a separate thread. It uses a context created using a sharegroup, so that the resulting framebuffer contents can be accessed directly as a texture for rendering by the main thread.

```
    myContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 sharegroup:mainGlContext.sharegroup];
```

When the third-party library finishes the render (which can take a long time) a callback alerts the main thread, which retrieves the textureID and renders it.

This all works fine *except*: there is an optional layer in the third-party library that has many, many objects, and takes an especially long time to render.  When I turn this layer on, the main thread often blocks while the third-party library is rendering, causing a drastic decrease in frame rate and a terrible user experience.

I want to be able to use that particular layer.  The long render time isn't a problem, but the blocking of the main thread definitely is.  I've verified that the third party calls are *not* made on the main thread.

I have instrumented this in Xcode using system trace... all of the blocking of the main thread rendering happens during the call into the third-party's render method, and seems to coincide with the offending layer's rendering

Could this be happening due to contention over the GPU by the two threads?  If so, is there a fix?  If not, what are other likely causes?